# #! as opposed to just # in a permalink

Tags: url, permalinks

I'm designing a permalink system and I just noticed that Twitter and Hipmunk both prefix their permalinks with `#!`. I was wondering why this is, and if the exclamation point in particular is there for a reason. Wouldn't `#/` work just as well, since they're no doubt using a framework that lets them redirect queries to certain templates with a regex URL parser?

`http://www.hipmunk.com/#!BOS.SEA,Dec15.Jan02`

`http://twitter.com/#!/dozba`

My only guess is it's because browsers use `#` to link to an anchor element. Is this why the exclamation point is appended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done to make an "AJAX" page crawlable [by google] for indexing -- It *does not* affect the other well-defined semantics of the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) at all!

See [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable: Getting Started](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html)

> Briefly, the solution works as follows: *the crawler finds a pretty AJAX URL (that is, **a URL containing a #! hash fragment**). It then requests the content for this URL from your server in a slightly modified form.* Your web server returns the content in the form of an HTML snapshot, which is then processed by the crawler. The search results will show the original URL.

I am sure other search-engines are also following this lead/protocol.

Happy coding.

---

Also, It is actually perfectly valid, at least per HTML5, to have an element with an ID of "!foo" so the 
reasoning in the post is invalid. See the article ["The id attribute just got more classy"](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class):

> HTML5 gets rid of the additional restrictions on the id attribute. The only requirements left — apart from being unique in the document — are that the value must contain at least one character (can’t be empty), and that it can’t contain any space characters.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that both pages use this in their JavaScript to differ between `#` (a link to an anchor) and their custom `#!` which loads some additional content using Ajax.

In that case pretty much everything else would work after the `#` sign.